# Which would be better: A unique_ptr to a 2D array or a 2D array of unique_ptrs?

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr

I'm currently in the middle of making an old project of mine memory-safe.

In this project I have a 2D array populated with pointers to instances of my own class `Block`.

declared like so:

```
Block* gemGrid[xMax][yMax];
```

and populated later like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<8; j++)
    {
        //do stuff here
        gemGrid[i][j] = new Block(i,j, gridOffset);
    }
}
```

This works fine.

I had the idea of creating a 2D array of `unique_ptr<Block>` instead of `Block*`.

Which i decided to declare like so:

```
unique_ptr<Block> gemGrid[xMax][yMax];
```

and populate like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<8; j++)
    {
        gemGrid[i][j].reset( new Block(i,j, gridOffset));
    }
}
```

However when I try this the compiler decides to completely ignore the second for loop (the 'j' incremented section), and create only a one dimensional array.

Which leads me to ask, does `C++` have a problem with `unique_ptrs` in 2D arrays? And should I just stick with a 2D array of pointers to `Block`s, and have one `unique_ptr` make sure this array is killed-of when it goes out of scope?

Comment: Why are you even using pointers to blocks? `Block gemGrid[xMax][yMax];` seems fine to me (though I can't not mention `std::vector<Block>` if sizes are not fixed at compile time)

Comment: I realized this as I was typing. Arrays decay to pointers anyway don't they?
However, this is as I populate using the 'new' keyword, and I'd like a way to have them automatically destroyed as the array goes out-of-scope.

Comment: That's not even relevant here.

Comment: The block instances need to be destroyed at some point. Sorry I have edited the comment above.

Comment: Oh, and the size is fixed. xMax & yMax are const.

Comment: If it wasn't clear yet: this is not Java. You don't need `new`. Stop using it and all the issues it brings go away. (i.e. `Block gemGrid[xMax][yMax];` just works without any manual intervention)

Comment: "the compiler decides to completely ignore the second for loop (the 'j' incremented section), and create only a one dimensional array." This seems unlikely. The for loop has absolutely no effect on what dimension the array is. The dimension of the array is determined by its definition, and you have shown a definition of a 2-D array. The problem likely is something other than what you think it is.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes maybe `Block` has only c-tor with parameters, that's why OP created array of `Block*` ?

Comment: No, C++ has no problem with 2D arrays of `unique_ptr`s, you must be doing something wrong and not realising it.  Still, why can't you just do `Block gemGrid[xMax][yMax]` as suggested?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't need 'new'? Even when creating a new instance of an object for the sole purpose of being pointed to by a pointer?

Comment: @borisbn, C++11 supports initializing array elements individually, not just default-constructing them

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean, the object's sole purpose is to be pointed to by a pointer? I doubt it, as that's a pretty useless object. Why do you think you need pointers?

Comment: and @SteveJessop That's exactly what I thought, but if I go back and undo the changes I've made, it works fine.
I may have misexplained this. The Array **is** a 2D array. But for some reason only initialized in one dimension.
I mean when the problem is occurring, visual studio's debugger actors like the variable 'j' literally does not exist. However, you make perfect sense and I will retrace my changes again.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean: well if it's not a bizarre debugger glitch then I'd guess there's some bug in the code in the inner loop, that has allowed the compiler to optimize it away.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean recheck, that `xMax` and `yMax` are exactly equals `8` or change `for` cicles to these constants instead of *hardcode* `8`

Comment: @JonathanWakely The objects purpose sorry, is to exist in an Array where it can be incrementally accessed along with the rest of it's kind. For this it needed to be created and initialised in a way that does not require a unique variable name. That is why I've been using the new keyword. I thought it was necessary for incrementally filling an array with new instances. I must have my C++ and Java mixed up.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean Here is a code you provided - [code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/46R7LS$2) - as you can see it works fine

Comment: Objects in an array don't have unique names, e.g. `block[i][j]` has no unique name, using `new` is orthogonal to that. As for the compiler deciding to "completely ignore the second for loop" my crystal ball tells me your inner loop does `i++` not `j++` so you never see `j` incremented

Comment: Here's the code without using `new` http://liveworkspace.org/code/BBOhw$2 (this default constructs the array elements then re-assigns a new value to them, which does more work, but doesn't leak anything)

Comment: The reason I had the idea of a 2D array of unique_ptrs to Blocks is so that once the array goes out of scope, all the elements will be disposed of cleanly. And the program itself performs many operations on the array throughout. changing the instances of the blocks pointed to by the array, etc. So I thought unique pointers with their release and reset functions would be a clean way to dispose of the discarded objects when they were done with. The old way of arrays of raw pointers was stupid , I now acknowledge this. But unfortunately im still not being allowed to iterate through my for loops.

Comment: And my second for loop definitely increments j via j++.

Comment: Okay, I've found a 'kind-of' solution to this problem. I have my 2D-Array of unique pointers now. One of the blocks was being prematurely release, and I had to fiddle with a few things for an Access violation error to fall out of hiding. So my grid of blocks now works. 
HOWEVER, if i put a break in my code and inspect my elements, the gemGrid[][] array still only shows up in the inspector as a  1-D array, and perfectly describes my first row of blocks. But the rest of the blocks **still exist!** and are drawn and displayed. So the array exists as a 2D array. VS just doesn't acknowledge this.

Comment: this is obviously a matter for another thread. Just thought I'd give this thread some closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ has no objection whatever to a 2-D array of `unique_ptr`.

The two alternatives you offer don't seem like real alternatives to me. If you have a `unique_ptr` to a 2-D array of `Block*`, and you allocate `xMax * yMax` instances of `Block` using `new` and store pointers to them in your array, then who or what is going to free those instances of `Block`? Certainly the `unique_ptr` is not. So the answer to "should I just do that" is almost certainly "no", because you'll have memory leaks.

The most "obvious" way to allocate a 2-D layout of instances of `Block` is to define a 2-D array of `Block` (either using a builtin array or `std::array` if available). If you can identify anything about that that doesn't suit you, then someone can suggest an alternative way for your old code to avoid memory leaks.

[In response to a comment above] Having done `Block gemGrid[xMax][yMax];`, you can get a pointer to one of your Block objects, if you need one, like this: `&gemGrid[i][j]`. Needing a pointer has absolutely nothing to do with memory allocation. Pointers *are* the means by which `new` lets you access the objects it allocates, but you can take a pointer to an object regardless of how it is allocated.